# How can i change the elements of a column in a matrix based on the changes in another column?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix 5x2 and looks like this :

```
1  0.25
2  0.125
3  0.0625
4  0.0625
5  0.5
```

My problem here is that when I sort the second column then the matrix changes to this form:

```
1  0.5
2  0.25
3  0.125
4  0.0625
5  0.0625
```

I need the first column to be changed as well based on the changes made in the second column, because I basically want every element of the first column to be assigned to the element of the second column. Like this:

```
5   0.5
1  0.25
2  0.125
3  0.0625
4  0.0625
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to sort the rows in descending order according to the second column?

```
sortrows(a,2,'descend')

ans =

    5.0000    0.5000
    1.0000    0.2500
    2.0000    0.1250
    3.0000    0.0625
    4.0000    0.0625
```

Comment: It appears that there is no command sortrows with 'descend' inside it .But i changed my code a little bit and it worked perfectly .Thank you a lot!

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΓιαννάκος you must be in an old version of MATLAB then, I have tried that

Answer (score 2):

Use [`sortrows(matrix,2)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html), or `[~,idx] = sort(matrix(:,2));matrix = matrix(idx,:)`.

The former, as it name suggests, sort matrices row-wise. The latter uses the second output of `sort()`, which are the sorted indices, allowing you to then change your entire matrix per row using indexing.